# No able to create a cursor PL/SQL (concurrents)

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have this query that tells me the last status of the different concurrents

```
  select 'The concurrent '||program||' with request_id '||request_id||' ended with status '|| 
           status as message, request_id
    from
    (
       <the subquery>
      )
   where rn = 1
     and status in ('WARNING','ERROR','STAND BY');
```

It works just fine; inside **the subquery** i put the name of the different concurrents that i want to check.

Everytime it runs i got this output (in this case i got 2 rows because i put the name of 2 concurrents inside **the subquery**

> |The concurrent Sales with request_id 987987678 ended with status
>   WARNING|987987678
>
> |The concurrent Prices with request_id 457857458 ended with status
>   WARNING|457857458

**I want to send that information via mail because i dont want to run it manually everytime**

That's why i decided to create a procedure and a cursor

```
create or replace procedure pr_mail_me is

  v_email_test varchar2(100) := 'myemail@random.com';

cursor crs_request is

  select 'The concurrent '||program||' with request_id '||request_id||' ended with status '|| 
           status as message, request_id
    from
    (
       <the subquery>
      )
   where rn = 1
     and status in ('WARNING','ERROR','STAND BY');  

begin

  for c in crs_request
  loop
  begin


      utl_mail.send(sender => 'sendercompany@test.com',recipients => v_email ,subject => 'Concurrents' ,message => c.message);
   end;
  end loop;

end;
```

The function that sends the email is this:

```
utl_mail.send(sender => 'sendercompany@test.com',recipients => v_email ,subject => 'Concurrents' ,message => c.message);
```

I am stuck on this, i want to send the previous information to multiple  email addresses but my code is not right. Could you please help me to modify my cursor?

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In particular for this just what are you getting?An error message, a run time error and if either **exactly** what. Looking carefully at the cursor the suspect is "rn=1". Is rn a column in the table, if not it's undefined or perhaps you mean rownum.

Comment: Wild guess: you declare `v_email_test` but you use `v_email`, and the procedure gives compilation errors including `PLS-00201: identifier 'v_email' must be declared`.